# Numerical optimization of a generic function

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, numerical-optimization

I am new in the topic of numerical optimization and I am interested in the solution of the following problem. Consider a two-parameter function like

$$
g(\omega_1, \omega_2)
$$

such that I can numerically evaluate it but I don't know the analytical dependence of $g$ with respect to the parameters.

Is there a generic method to find the global minimum of $g$ with this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you would like to find a minimum or a maximum of $g$ over some set in $\Omega_1 \times \Omega_2$, possibly the entire $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Assuming $g$ is nice (e.g., continuous) you can use conjugate direction methods, like [Powell's Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powell's_method). If $g$ is differentiable, there are better methods using the gradient if you can numerically compute it.

Here is a nice [discussion on Gradient Descent](http://www.onmyphd.com/?p=gradient.descent) method with some examples.

Comment: Thank you! Well, your assumption is correct. Do you know if there is any method for finding specifically the global minimum?

Comment: @dapias It makes no difference if you minimize or maximize, since if the maximum of $g$ is at $(a,b)$, then $(a,b)$ is the minimum of $-g$... Generally all optimization algorithms by default minimize for that reason.

Comment: you are absolutely right. I was wondering about the difference of finding local minima instead of the global one

Comment: @dapias Global is hard. If $g$ is convex, then they coincide and life is nice ;-). If not, you have to start your optimization in different parts of the space, or use something entirely different, like simulated annealing algorithms, and even then there are no guarantees.