# Numerical optimization of unknown n-variable function subject to constraints

Tags: inequality, nonlinear-optimization

I'm trying to optimize a certain 3D (meshed) structure. Optimization is done by segmenting the structure in a known quantity of different pieces and assigning different Young's moduli to these different pieces. Afterwards a simulation is ran to calculate the Von Mises stresses in the structure.

The objective function is to have as much nodes with Von Mises stress within a known interval around a known value (the model value differs from node to node but is always known).

A constraint is that the stress in every node should stay below the yield stress in the material.

I read here: [Numerical optimization of a generic function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2102265/numerical-optimization-of-a-generic-function)

That for a similar 2D-problem Powell's method could be used. However in that case there were no constraints and in this case it wouldn't be 2D but rather 75D. On the other side every iteration is very costly since I have to run a simulation every time.

-What is the best optimization strategy, that can handle inequality constraints, for this problem ?

To clarify the problem further, this figure is token from Arabnejad et al. (2017). I'm trying to solve a similar problem:
[Problem clarification figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrIm4.png)

All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still use Powell's method, which can use any number of inputs. The constraints are handled simply by checking each iteration satisfies them before you calculate your function value. If the new iteration does not satisfy the constraints, then find the place where the line segment from the old iteration to the new iteration crosses the boundary and back up to this point.

Minimizing 75 variables by search will be expensive timewise, but I've done worse and still was able to compute results in a reasonable amount of time.

Concerning using Brent's method to optimize each search vector, one problem I've found with it is that the new iterations have a tendency to always fall on the same side of the root, leaving the other side far away, until the method eventually brings it in by slow bisection steps. A trick I've used to some improvement is to intentionally double the stepsize that Brent's method calculates, in order to overshoot the root and bring the opposite side in as well. This usually speeds up convergence even on the side that was converging.  I am not familiar with the other method suggested in the wikipedia article, but I suspect you will find a similar problem with most methods.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Paul! Now that I know that I could use it, would you also recommend Powell's method for a problem like this, or is there another more adequate method?

Comment: Sorry to take so long to get back to you - I couldn't get into MSE yesterday. I'm not that familiar with Powell's method. I just looked it up on Wikipedia, and saw that it was adaptable to your situation. However, I have used something similar before - maybe even the same, I didn't examine it that closely. I can't really recommend for or against it.

Comment: No problem, since I have no other real optimizationn strategies for now I'll try this first. I'll let you know how it went (if I don't forget), although it will still take a couple of months before I reach the optimization stage.